# Uses or overrides a deprecated API (Android Java)

Tags: java, android

a ver, tengo un problema al compilar mi aplicación con Android Studio, lo cierto es que la ejecuta sin problemas, pero me salta el error del título. Según he leido es por usar algún método que se desaconseja o que está obsoleto, pero no se cual podría ser, os dejo el código:

```
    package com.isaac.appet;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException;


public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText etEmailLogin;
    private EditText etPassLogin;
    private Button btnRegister;
    private Button btnLogin;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        etEmailLogin = findViewById(R.id.etEmailLogin);
        etPassLogin = findViewById(R.id.etPassLogin);
        btnRegister = findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void userRegister() {

        String email = etEmailLogin.getText().toString().trim();
        String pass = etPassLogin.getText().toString().trim();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No olvides escribir tu email, lo necesitas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Que cabeza la tuya, no has metido la clave", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        progressDialog.setMessage("Dame un segundo que te apunto en la lista de gente chachi");
        progressDialog.show();

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Te has registrado con éxito, tus mascotas lo agradecen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Este usuario ya se encuentra registrado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Vaya, no he podido registrarte, lo siento", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }

                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

    }

    private void userLogin() {

        final String email = etEmailLogin.getText().toString().trim();
        String pass = etPassLogin.getText().toString().trim();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No olvides escribir tu email, lo necesitas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Que cabeza la tuya, no has metido la clave", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        progressDialog.setMessage("Accediendo a darle amor a tus mascotas, wof wof");
        progressDialog.show();

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();


                        } else {
                            if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Este usuario ya se encuentra registrado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Este usuario no está registrado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }

                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.btnRegister:

                userRegister();
                break;

            case R.id.btnLogin:

                userLogin();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

No se que estaré usando que esté obsoleto, este código lo que hace es conectar con firebase para crear un login, nada más. A ver si me podéis echar una mano. Y no se que más escribir para que me deje publicar el post, así que estas últimas lineas podéis obviarlas.

Comment: ¿En tu IDE no te identifica el *warning*? Por ejemplo en Eclipse las identifica con un subrayado amarillo. ¿Qué IDE estás usando?

Comment: @SJuan76 estoy utilizando Android Studio, se he usado métodos que aparecían tachados, no se si esto tiene algo que ver

Comment: Probablemente, pasa el ratón por encima del método y creo que te mostrará el mensaje explicando porqué está tachado. Y en todo caso ahora que tienes algunos métodos "sospechosos", puedes repasar el Javadoc para ver qué te dice de esos métodos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que ves es un `Warning` no un error en si, te dice que el metodo esta obsoleto te compilara pero debes tener en cuenta que no hay soporte ya para ese metodo.

La solucion:

ver el metodo que te esta marcando y buscar la sustitucion segun la documentacion oficial

Comment: ¿Como veo el método que me está marcando?

Comment: Era el método progressDialog que ya se encuentra en desuso, en la actualidad se utiliza progressBar.